# Edittext field completely empty, after using settext()

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, google-geocoder, smsmanager

I am trying to insert the address fetched from the `geocoder`API, into my `edittext` field. After granting the location permission in my app, no text gets inserted in my `edittext` field, and even the SMS permission isn't called too.

My code:

```
public class message extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edittext;
    Button send;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    ArrayList<String> contacts=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        send = findViewById(R.id.button);
        edittext = findViewById(R.id.msg);


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        contacts = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("contacts");


        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(message.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    if (location != null){
                        try {
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(message.this, Locale.getDefault());
                            List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                            Log.d("address", address.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                            edittext.setText(address.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                            
                            sos_message();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(message.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);


    }

    private void sos_message() {
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(message.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    try {
                        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

                        if ((contacts != null) || (edittext.getText().toString().length() != 0)) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
                                sms.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(contacts.get(i)), null, edittext.getText().toString(), null, null);
                            }
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message sent successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.show();
                        } else {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(message.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 44);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml** permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Have you overriden `onRequestPermissionsResult` method inside your activity? This method has to be implemented so that your permission request should be handled. Please check here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: And the reason why the sms permission is not being called might be because of location being returned null and it didn't pass the if condition in `if (location != null){`

Comment: The Geocoder class backend is only present on Google-approved devices. So the lookup will basically fail on any device that doesn't have GMail/Market/Maps on it.

Comment: @KidusTekeste It sure does ask for location permission when I run the app, but my address is never fetched and inserted into the `edittext` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kidus Tekeste, I discovered that my `location` object was actually showing to be  null. This piece of code solves the problem:

```
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); // 5 seconds
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(location.getLatitude());
                        stringBuilder.append("-");
                        stringBuilder.append(location.getLongitude());
                        stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
                        Toast.makeText(message.this,stringBuilder,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //txtContinueLocation.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

                        if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    if((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(message.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(message.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ){

        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null){

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(message.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> address = null;
                    try {
                        address = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("address", address.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                    edittext.setText(address.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                    sos_message();
                }
                else{
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }else
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                44);
```